# Table numbering in texreg output

Tags: r, r-markdown, texreg

[Texreg](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/texreg/vignettes/texreg.pdf) is the only package I found that produces nicely formatted Latex  tables for multi-level regression (e.g., `lmer`).

The generated table caption is "Table N: *caption*", where N is the number of texreg tables in the document up to that point, including the current table. The *caption* text can be set using the `caption` parameter, but I can't find a way to change the "Table N:"

This is an issue if other types of tables (e.g., xtable) are also used in the same RMarkdown/knitr document.

Is there a way to modify this part of the caption without manually changing the compiled `.tex` file?

Answer (score 2):

`texreg` creates a `tabular` environment that contains the actual table. By default, `texreg` additionally wraps this `tabular` environment in a `table` float, which positions the table on the page and creates the caption. If you choose to do this manually, you can use `texreg`'s argument `table = FALSE`. In that case, you may want to write the code for the `table` float manually in your LaTeX file and possibly adjust the caption in custom ways:

```
\begin{table}
  <insert texreg output with table = FALSE here>
  \caption{My table}
\end{table}
```

You can edit the caption manually or redefine the caption command to do whatever you want. [This source](http://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=22461) contains some useful suggestions on how to redefine the appearance of the caption.